# I am unable to install or uninstall any packages due to an error in the process "dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-legacy"

Tags: 20.04, dpkg

I am very new to ubuntu. For one of my classes, I had to download virtualbox, but somehow I managed to botch the installation and it didn't work. After purging virtualbox from my system, i started getting this error. Now I can't seem to install or uninstall any sort of packages. I've tried using solutions from different forum, like dpkg --configure -a, for sudo-get update, i've tried installing xserver-xorg-legacy again, but nothing.

this is the what I'm seeing:

```
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up xserver-xorg-legacy (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another p
rocess: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-legacy (--configure):
 installed xserver-xorg-legacy package post-installation script subprocess retur
ned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-legacy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Screenshots of text are much harder to read than the text when copied & pasted into your question. We also can't copy details from a picture to look up information to respond to you. so for us to help you, you should make it easy for us to help.

Comment: i apologize, hopefully this edit is better

Comment: Make sure you don't have another process (different window, different workspace, you didn't say if this was server or desktop so even another user) which has a question waiting to be answered thus is holding the lock.

Comment: it's on laptop. the only other window running is google chrome